# Data drive Background in Specflow

Tags: selenium-webdriver, specflow

Have 2 scenarios to run across 2 different users -

What I wish to achieve is as below, but not possible as cannot include 2 backgrounds in one feature

Background:
Select User A -
Scenario Outline:
Validate clicking on link abc, xyz take me to 1 & 2 page.

Background:
Select User B -
Scenario Outline:
Validate clicking on link abc, xyz take me to 3 & 4 page.

Have used Specflow Excel to handle the Scenario outline, but the Background step -have included as part of scenario, so this is being run for each scenario. I want the User to be selected once & the link check done against it.
How implemented currently

Scenario Outline:
Select User B -
Validate clicking on link abc, xyz take me to 3 & 4 page.

Do we have @ BeforeScenario tags to do this?

```
 Scenario Outline: ABC Link check - Page
    When User searches for XYZ on ID field
    And User can access <Page>
    Then Control <Loc> with <Ctrl> displays

Scenario Outline: XYZ Link check - Page
    When User searches for XYZ on ID field
    And User can access <Page>
    Then Control <Loc> with <Ctrl> displays

@source:userNavigation.xlsx:SMSF
Scenarios:
|Page|Loc|Ctrl|
```

Want to push first When step to background steps. have 2 Examples defined here.

Comment: Sample specflow scenario please.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to use a Examples table and pass in parameters to check in the then statement along with the user.

```
Scenario Outline: Scenario name
.....
Then the user '<user>' sees the page '<page>'
Examples:
| user  | page  |
| userA | pageA |
| userB | pageB |
```